# FlatList in React Native does not display any content

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-android

I just learned that there is a flatList in React Native. I have a list of services, when the user tap on each service, they are redirected to the address where those services are available. I am trying to display these addresses in FlatList. The screen shot of the list of services is below:

[image]

when the user taps on Test service, I want to show the address in the form of FlatList. I am not sure, but whatever I am displaying inside flatList is not showing on the page. Below is my entire code including flatlist:

```
     /**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, Linking, Button, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getTheme } from 'react-native-material-kit';
import EvilIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons';
import MaterialIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import SimpleIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons';
import * as actions from '../actions';
import getDirections from 'react-native-google-maps-directions'
const theme = getTheme();

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    marginTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 20,
    marginBottom: 20,
    borderColor: 'lightgrey',
    borderWidth: 0.5,
  },

  container: {     
    flex: 1, 
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    alignItems: 'center', 
    backgroundColor: '#4F6D7A', 
    height: 500,
    alignSelf:'center',
    width:500,
    position: 'relative',
    marginTop: 5,
    top: 10
  }, 

  title1: {
      top: 10,
      left: 80,
      fontSize: 24,
  },
  title2: {
      top: 35,
      left: 82,
      fontSize: 18,
  },
  image: {
      flex: 0,
      height: 100,
      width: 333,
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
  },
  closeIcon: {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 5,
      left: 295,
      color: 'black'

  },  
  icon: {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 15,
      left: 0

  },
  textArea: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      paddingLeft: 20,
      paddingTop: 10,
      width: 260,
  },
  textIcons: {
      color: '#26a69a',
  },
  actionArea: {
      paddingTop: 10,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-around',
      alignItems: 'center',
  },

  title:{
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 22,
    color: 'black'
    },

    SerContent:{
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 16,
        paddingTop: 10,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        color: 'black'
    },

    underLineText: {
        fontSize: 17,
        textDecorationLine: 'underline',
        color: 'black',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        alignSelf: 'center'


      },

      dir:{
        flexDirection:'row',
        paddingTop: 30,
        alignSelf: 'center',



    } , 

    dirAddr:{
        flexDirection:'column',
        paddingTop: 30,

        alignSelf: 'center'


    },

    Address1:{
        alignSelf: 'center',
        marginRight: 20,
        fontSize: 17,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: 'black'
    },

    fullAddress:{

        marginRight: 20,

        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: 'black'
    },
    toolbar:{
        flexDirection:'row' ,   //Step 1

    },
    toolbarTitle:{
        width: 10,
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0,
        flex:1                //Step 3
      },
      buttonShape:{

        margin: 40,
        width:160,
        marginLeft: 80,
        backgroundColor:'#00BCD4',


    },



producetBox:{
        margin:10, 
        fontWeight:'bold',
        color:'#000',
        alignSelf:'center'

},

price:{

    padding:5,
    margin:10,
    borderColor:'orange',
    borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
}

});



class ServiceDetail extends Component {
    handleClick = (link) => {
        Linking.canOpenURL(link).then(suppported => {
            if (supported) {
                Linking.openURL(link);
            } else {
                console.log('Don\'t know how to open URI: ' + link);
            }
        });
    };


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          latitude: null,
          longitude: null,
          error: null,
        };
      }

 componentDidMount()
 {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
          this.setState({
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude,
            error: null,
          });
        },
        (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
      );

 }



  render() {





var online="";
var destUrl = 'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Current+Location/' +  this.props.services.destAddr1 ;

var destUrl1 ='https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Current+Location/' +  this.props.services.destAddr2 ;


var Online=  this.props.services.onlineURL;

return (


     <View>
      <View style={styles.toolbar}>
            <Image 
                 resizeMode='contain'
                 style={styles.toolbarTitle} 
                source={require('../Resources/AcrLogoWithDesc.jpg')} />
         </View>
         <View>

             <Text  style={styles.title}>{this.props.services.ser}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.SerContent} >Service is available in the following locations:</Text>
        </View>

        <View>
        <FlatList
           data={this.props.services}
            renderItem={({item})=>
            <View>
              <Text>{item.ser}</Text>
             </View>

        }
        />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.buttonShape}>
            <Button  onPress={() => this.props.noneSelected()} title = 'Close'/>
       </View>


   </View>



  );
}
}



const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { 
        services: state.serviceSelected
     };
  };



export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(ServiceDetail);

I can see the content of {this.props.services.ser}, but I cannot see the content of  <Text>{item.services.ser}</Text> which is inside the flatList. below is the screen shot of the service details when the user taps on Test service:
```

Item.services.serv content is not appearing on my second screen shot. Below is my JSON and the screen shot of resulting screen file":

[image]

[

```
{
    "id":0,
    "ser": "Test Service",
    "Location": "TestLoc",
    "Phone1":"(999)-999-5050",
    "SecondLoc": "TestLoc2",
    "email":"test@test.com",
    "sourceLat":"33.977806",
    "sourceLong":"-117.373261",
    "destLatL1":"33.613355",
    "destLongL1":"-114.596569",
    "destLatL2":"33.761693",
    "destLongL2":"-116.971169",
    "destAddr1": "Test Address, Test Drive",
    "destAddr2": "Test Address2, Test Drive2",
    "onlineURL":"",
    "Phone2": "(900)-900-3333"
  },
```

]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiZMp.png
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. I tried below things for the flatList

```
<View>
        <FlatList
           data={this.props.services}
           keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.services.id}
            renderItem={({item})=>
            <View>
              <Text>{item.ser}</Text>
             </View>

        }
        />
        </View>
```

This is another way that I tried:

```
  <View>
        <FlatList
            style={{}}
                data={this.props.services}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key}
                renderItem={(rowData) =>this.RenderFeedCard(rowData)}
        />
        </View>
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the JSON that you provide is for this.props.services. So the call inside renderItem={({item})=>  {item.services.ser} should be {item.ser} instead.

The reason why is because Flatlist 'data' takes an array (eg: this.props.services) and 'renderItem' will take each item (this.props.services[0]) of the array and do something about it. So you only have to write {item.ser} in order to get the string.

Comment: I am still not seeing anything on my phone screen. Nothing inside the flatlist is getting displayed on the phone screen. I updated my code above.

Comment: Have you tried adding keyExtractor = { (item, index) => index } to the Flatlist?

Comment: I tried adding KeyExtractor and also renderfeedCard. I updated my above post. If you scroll to my post. i mentioned that I tried below things for flatList. I provided two ways that I tried the flatList.

Answer (score 0):

```
renderItem={({item})=>(
  <View>
  <Text>{item.ser}</Text>
  </View>
)}
```

Comment: If this is an answer to the question, please [edit] your answer to add some context to the code.